# Как добавить плавность в клике? Я нажимаю на кнопку,она меняется,но очень быстро,как мне сделать чтобы она плавно и медленно менялась?

Tags: java, android-studio, анимация

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
image = findViewById(R.id.image);

```
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (connected==0)
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.vpn_jpg);
                connected=1;
            }
            else
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.___2023_10_31_16_42_39_transformed);
                connected=0;
            }
```